# Low-latency real-time audio streaming over UDP

Tags: udp, audio-streaming

So I'm sort of lost and need some direction for research.

I want to build a real-time audio chat environment with as low latency as possible.

I've done a little research and it looks like I have to use the UDP over TCP protocol, but I'm unsure of how to do this.

If I had a dedicated server running lamp, would I run a separate application listen for and serve UDP packets?

Any direction woudl be appreciated.

Comment: UDP doesn't run over TCP, they are at the same layer.  Both UDP and TCP run over IP.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "over" as "instead of." I was thinking at first that I could somehow receive UDP with an apache server somehow, but I now realize I nee to build a separate UDP server/client. Can I run this along the same hardware as my apache server?

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  No, Apache is an HTTP server which uses TCP.  Yes, you can run whatever you want on the same hardware.  Also, rather that reinventing the wheel here, why don't you outline your specific requirements so we can suggest something that already exists?  For instance, WebRTC.

Comment: My goal was to be able to stream two-way audio between multiple users on separate devices. So I would do this by setting up a UDP client/server on each device that are routed through a main UDP client/server on my dedicated server. I'm not sure if that makes sense this is all out of my field. I'm not sure WebRTC will work, because it's browser based.

Comment: What devices?  What are your latency requirements?  How about audio quality?  Do you get to choose which codecs you use, or do you have to use what is supported by the device?

Comment: I'd like to start with a single family of devices say iOS. I was planning on trying to transmit whatever codec the stream was given to me in. I have no latency requirement. I am just trying to get it as low as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way when it comes to audio or video is to always use the UDP protocol, this protocol does not provide error control,  UDP is connectionless protocol that tells me that when you send a  data over UDP  you don't know if it'll get there, can occur corruption while transferring, to audio or video this can be a nice idea !

You can create dedicated server listening in UDP port to receive all data and pass to the corresponding client!

You need learn about socket programming, choose your preferred language and learn how use socket, this is the way.